# How to add group while creating Invoices - IPP Data Service - QuickBooks Desktop version

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

we have a group named "Payment Group". In that group 
two items are there Books, Tire Repair. We are trying to add this group in invoice. But we are facing issues while creating the invoice.

```
QBInvoiceService iInvoiceSer = QBServiceFactory.getService(platformSessionContext, QBInvoiceService.class);
 QBInvoice myInvoice = QBObjectFactory.getQBObject(platformSessionContext, QBInvoice.class);


  InvoiceHeader invoiceHeader = QBObjectFactory.getQBObject(platformSessionContext, InvoiceHeader.class);
  invoiceHeader.setCustomerName("John");
  invoiceHeader.setPONumber("999");
  invoiceHeader.setSalesTermName("Net 10");
  Calendar dueDate = Calendar.getInstance();
  dueDate.set(2013, 12, 01);
  invoiceHeader.setDueDate(dueDate);

  ArrayList<InvoiceLine> invoiceLineList = new ArrayList<InvoiceLine>();
  InvoiceLine invoiceLine = QBObjectFactory.getQBObject(platformSessionContext, InvoiceLine.class);
  invoiceLine.setItemName("Payment Group");   

  InvoiceLine invoiceLine1 = QBObjectFactory.getQBObject(platformSessionContext, InvoiceLine.class);
  invoiceLine1.setItemName("Books"); 
  invoiceLine1.setDesc("");
  invoiceLine1.setAmount(new BigDecimal(500));
  invoiceLine1.setQty(new BigDecimal(5));

  InvoiceLine invoiceLine2 = QBObjectFactory.getQBObject(platformSessionContext, InvoiceLine.class);
  invoiceLine2.setItemName("Tire Repair");
  invoiceLine2.setDesc("Tire Repair");
  invoiceLine2.setAmount(new BigDecimal(500));
  invoiceLine2.setQty(new BigDecimal(5));

  InvoiceLine invoiceLine3 = QBObjectFactory.getQBObject(platformSessionContext, InvoiceLine.class);
  invoiceLine3.setDesc("group description");
  invoiceLine3.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1000));    

invoiceLineList.add(invoiceLine);
invoiceLineList.add(invoiceLine1);
invoiceLineList.add(invoiceLine2);  

ArrayList<TaxLine> taxLineList = new ArrayList<TaxLine>();
           TaxLine taxLine = QBObjectFactory.getQBObject(platformSessionContext, TaxLine.class);
           taxLine.setTaxName("Net 10");
           taxLineList.add(taxLine);

           myInvoice.setHeader(invoiceHeader);
           myInvoice.setLine(invoiceLineList);
           myInvoice.setTaxLine(taxLineList);

           QBInvoice newInvoice = iInvoiceSer.addInvoice(platformSessionContext, myInvoice);
```

invoice is creating successfully. But not syncing with Desktop QuickBooks Software.
Any idea reagrding this ? Is it possible to add group items while creating
invoice using ipp Java devkit 2.0.7 ? API's is available or not ?

Comment: Which version and edition of QuickBooks software you are using ?

Comment: QuickBooks Premier Edition 2011.